# How do I get my phone to ring on a calendar notification?

Tags: notifications, ringtone

I'm always missing appointments because the event notifications in Calendar app are so pathetic.

I when its time to leave for an appointment, I want my phone to ring as loud as possible as if I'm getting a phone call, and to continue ringing until I turn it off.

Is there any app/SaaS for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are apps available ( listed at end ) but IMO , [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) is the preferred way for this since :

- You are looking for *conditional* actions
- Customisation options to suit individual needs

I prefer using [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app because it's free ( upto 5 macros ) and very easy to learn

---

You would need two macros for this

(Triggers / Actions / Constraints are added by **`+`**   on the right side of each panel )

**Logic:**

- *Ring on Calendar Notif Macro :*   Whenever you get a notification from your calendar app, alert you with a non - stop ringing , at a volume level and sound customised by you
- *Stop Ringing Macro :*  *Manually* stop the ringing using a widget on your home screen and set the Volume levels to what you would prefer in your normal device usage

Barebone implementation of this logic is implemented in Macros below. You can customise it later by experimenting

[image]
[image]

---

**Don't** get intimidated by the long explanation - it's detailed so that you don't waste time setting it up ; shouldn't take you more than 5 minutes to set up :)

**Ring on Calendar Notif** Macro

- **Trigger:** Notification Received → Select your calendar app  → Text  → Any
- **Actions**
- Set Macrodroid Variable  → New Variable  → Stop Ringing , Type *Boolean*  → Set it to *false*  (initialising variable that controls when to stop / start ringing )
- Repeat Actions ( second item on drop down when you press the plus sign on action panel ) → While condition repeat → Conditions **`+`** → Macrodroid Variable → Stop Ringing  →`OK` → Select *False* and `OK`

This creates a while / do loop wherein we want you to be sued when notification arrives something to be done when . You see now a WHILE / DO - End Loop created . Tap the *End Loop* and you will get a pop up *Add action above*. Tap that and add actions below

- Volume Change → select *Media / Music* and set slider to say maximum % tap `OK`
- Play → select any sound from drop down list
- Wait before next action → set it to 2 seconds

**Constraints:** Leave blank

**Stop Ringing** Macro

- **Trigger:**  Empty Trigger

**Actions**

- Set Macrodroid Variable Stop Ringing to *True*
- Volume Change - set the Volume levels you normally have on your device

**Constraints:** Leave blank

Go to the widgets section of your launcher , drag and drop Macrodroid widget to your home screen and assign it to Stop Ringing macro

**Alternative app option**

- [Calendar event Reminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.mildev84.reminder) claims ( not tested by me ) to

> With this simple app you can override or replace default reminder with "unmissable" ones - they will ring like phone call how long you want, with melody you want!

- See Izzy's collection of [Calendar Alarm Fixes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_alarmfixes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution, you could use Llama.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama

It's an old app but very simple and powerful.

Give access to your notification by activating Llama in Accessibility settings of your phone.

- Create an event with condition as **app notification bar icon** of your calendar app
- Add action to that event as **play a sound** and choose a sound

That's it. Test the actions once and you are good to go.

*And not to forget, this app has no ads. It has no internet access at all. Salute the developer!*