# Always alert on a specific app's notifications?

Tags: notifications, google-pixel, 8.1-oreo

**My problem:**

I want to purchase event tickets that go on sale at a time not predisclosed. They're announced via Twitter and effectively sold out within 60-90 seconds. I only follow the handle that posts this announcement and receive no other notifications from Twitter.

**My question:**

Is it possible to make an arbitrary app (or even just Twitter) play a notification sound even when my phone is silenced?  Alternatives, such as elevating all of its notifications to emergencies or similar solutions would suffice as well.

Comment: Please look at [tag:automation] type apps on Play Store, such as Tasker, MacroDroid, Automate, etc. Most can do the task very easily.

Comment: I don't use Twitter but you can try the approach in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179187/131553). The first macro tweaked should do the job

Comment: If it works, you can post an answer yourself

Comment: Thank you for those pointers.  If either of you want to submit those as an answer with a bit more flesh, I'll give you the checkmark.